# Eclipse ADT not running on Windows XP

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-xp, eclipse-adt

I downloaded the ADT Bundle from the android developers website, and I choosed the 64 bits version. When I tried running eclipse, it didn't work and I got the error eclipse.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

I am running a 64 bits Windows XP machine. I checked it by ruuning dxdiag.exe :

[image]

I don't understand why it is not working. Any idea ?

Comment: dude you have x86 family, means you have 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i can see from your system information, your window xp is 32bit Operating System.

X86 represents 32-bit OS for Window XP.

Now you can do 2 things

First  - Download ADT Bundle for 32-Bit.

Second - Download Eclipse Only for 32-Bit and set the path of downloaded android SDK into Eclipse.